# Find string in a string, then find another line based on that string

Tags: c#, json, string, search

I reckon the title is pretty confusing, so here's what's happening. Below is a snippet of a JSON I've read into a TextBox. I'm currently coding in C# in VS 2012 Express.

```
      "activityStatus" : "Scheduled Enabled",
      "filterCategory2" : "Position1",
      "filterCategory3" : "RESUPPLY/OUTFIT",
      "origination" : "Company Name",
      "timeCritical" : false,
      "monitor" : false,
      "class" : "System",
      "annotationText" : "Install System Racks",
```

What I'd like to do is find every instance of "filterCategory2" : "Position1" in this great long JSON which I've imported as a string. Then, wherever the program finds a "filterCategory2" : "Position1", I'd like for it to scan a little further ahead for "annotationText" : "Install System Racks"

Now, it won't always say "Install System Racks". It might be something different, but it will always say "annotationText" and it will always be "filterCategory2" : "Position1". I'd like to pull out the "Install System Racks" and drop it elsewhere - e.g. a textbox or a word document or whatever. But I do want to capture *every* event. So there might be something like "Install System Racks" at one point, then "Decouple mating adapters" at another, and so on.

I'm very new to C# (just started yesterday :P). I'd like to figure this out on my own, so I'm not looking for code as much as I'm looking for guidance (though if it helps to guide me by using pieces of code, feel free!).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should just use a JSON parser like JSON.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Use a website, such as http://json2csharp.com/ to generate a C# class for your code.  Although this will depend on how the JSON information that you are getting is configured.

Use a JSON parser library such as JSON.NET from nuget to parse the file.

I am not sure what you mean by "...I'd like for it scan a little further ahead for.."

Comment: Scan was the wrong word choice. I just meant I wanted it to find the first instance of "annotationText" : "..." immediately after encountering "filterCategory2" : "...". I'll check out the website. Thanks.

Comment: Alright - got the converted C# code into my program and moving on to Salvador's recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jake, serialize your Jason into an object and then simply check that object for the information you want (if you serialize your Jason into myObject, for example):

```
if(myObject.FilterCategory2 == "Position1" && myObject.AnnotationText == "Install System Racks")
{
    // Do your thing with myObject.AnnotationText
}
```